# Pythonic way of tagging objects from iterators for later handling

Tags: python, inheritance, web-scraping, generator

A slightly strange question, but I'm currently working with a scraping setup in python that has methods generating one of a few different things. URLs to be scraped, and objects that have been scraped primarily.

If a URL is yielded then I want to take certain steps, such as checking for validity, adding a callback, etc... For reasonable separation of concerns, these steps don't happen in the main scraping function. This leaves me with something like this:

```
def scraper(response):
    # XML parsing
    yield URL(<your_url_here>)
    yield Item({"some": "dict"})

def handler(response):
    for item in scraper(response):
        if isinstance(item, URL):
            # Do something
        elif isinstance(item, Item):
            # Do something else
```

These scrapers are written by uses of the framework, and the handler can also be modified. The issue with this is that a URL is just a string, so making a custom URL class so that it can be caught in the handler is pretty un-pythonic. It's making a class just to be caught that has no public methods, which smells wrong to me.

The other issue is that since these scrapers can be overwritten, it's totally feasible that someone wants to yield some other string for some other reason, so checking just for BaseString membership seems pretty unpythonic as well.

Is there a more pythonic way to basically "tag" these generated objects for post-processing without making a shell of a class?

Comment: Why not just yield the Item with the 'url' as a key in it?

Comment: @Vincenzzzochi, Items usually have a url key associated with them, but we don't always want to revisit those urls. In fact, we usually don't, so it doesn't make an effective check.

Comment: The "do something" part sounds like something that could be a public method. `for item in scraper(response): item.process()`.

Comment: Just `yield` a tuple of values each time in the scraper.

Comment: @chepner Ideally yes, but in this case the "do something" is actually pretty heavy with a few context-specific dependencies. In reality it's wrapped in a larger object.

Comment: Why not yield a `urlparse.ParseResult` object from `scraper` (like so: `yield urlparse.parse(<your_url_here>)`) rather than a raw string? If it looks like a URL, it had better be a valid URL. This way, you get type-safety as well as URL validity checks for free.

Comment: @martineau that would be an option, but it feels like it would be a big step back in terms of usability and feels less pythonic to me. Maybe I'm nuts, but my thought was always that something explicit and semantic would be better than a combination of `yield (<magic_string>, item)` and `if item[0] == <magic_string>`. Maybe I'm missing something, but it feels gross and unpythonic allround. Maybe a `namedtuple` instead?

Comment: @Srikanth, I've got the url-checking elsewhere right now, but I think that a combination of your and martineau's suggestion might be the ticket. I'll probably post that up as an answer if nobody else does, or nobody else comes up with a better solution.

Comment: If defining, constructing and yielding a `namedtuple` makes you feel better, that would be almost equally efficient as a plain `tuple`—but it's really not much better than using a custom class. The main thing is to design things so what the code is doing is fairly obvious (and perhaps is easy to change).

Comment: @martineau yea, once I started writing this I realized we've still got the whole magic string problem, which is really unintuitive. I'm still using the custom class. Maybe that's pythonic enough and I'm just trying too hard here. I'm thinking a combination of a namedtuple and an enum would solve the magic string problem, but it seems decidedly less pythonic to me.